# JQuery UI Accordion getting data from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui-accordion

i have this webapplication which was created in VisualStudio 2010.

I want to display a "Faq"-page, which gets the questions from a database.
The answers are in a txt-file on the server.

So when I get the question list from the database I get a dataset like this :

```
ID = 1
Title = "Title1"
Answer = "\EN\1.txt"
```

On my webpage I have the following :

```
<div id="accordion" runat="server">        
</div>
```

In my codebehind, I have the following:

```
Private Sub AddQuestionToPage(row As DataRow)
    Try

        Dim headerControl = New LiteralControl()
        headerControl.Text = "<H3>" + row.Item(2) + "</H3>"
        accordion.Controls.Add(headerControl)

        Dim divcontrol = New LiteralControl()
        divcontrol.ID = "Faq_" + row.Item(0).ToString
        divcontrol.Text = GetHtmlFromFile(row.Item(3))
        accordion.Controls.Add(divcontrol)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function GetHtmlFromFile(path As String) As String
    'Open a file for reading
    Dim FILENAME As String = Server.MapPath("Answers\" + path)

    'Get a StreamReader class that can be used to read the file
    Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
    objStreamReader = File.OpenText(FILENAME)
    Dim contents As String = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

    Return contents

End Function
```

The txt-file looks as follows :

```
<div>
<p>
    This is the english reply
</p>
<p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
</p>
<p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
</p>
```

When I see my page i'm seeing the correct information.
But I'm not seeing it as an accordion.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `divcontrol.Text = GetHtmlFromFile(row.Item(3))` the text that has the answer must start with `<div>` and end with `</div>`, otherwise the accordion will be invalid.
Another way is to add that extra html before `Return contents`.

Comment: I've added the content of the txt-file in the question. The div-tags are there.

Comment: You missed the closing div tag, but I'm assuming it is there. How are you calling the accordion function? Like this: `$( "#accordion" ).accordion();` ? ASP.NET changes the ids of the elements, if that is how you are calling the function, try to change to `$( "#<%= accordion.ClientID %>" ).accordion();`.

Comment: It was solved when i did the $( "#<%= accordion.ClientID %>" ).accordion();